# Significant air in water lines

Tags: plumbing, well

Almost a month ago we had a new well tank installed, the brand is called Mainline. Immediately after installation we had lots of air in the lines. We have a small tenant house on the premises and a barn that shares the water lines from the house it is an old property, air was in all those lines .

There were some instances of some discoloration in the water at times in the cold lines. It did seem to improve over the next week or so but then five days ago I used our furnace because we had a cold snap and immediately the next day we had terrible air in the lines all over again, every time we flush the toilet to using the hydrant at the barn and even in my tenant house .

I do not know if it's related to turning on the furnace or it's still a continuing problem. We didn't have this issue until the well tank was replaced and would love some ideas as to what to do next as the plumber who installed it is not able to respond at this time.

Your thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a hydronic furnace? Wondering why that would make any difference. What type of pump? Jet or submersible?

Comment: I'm not sure if "Unable to respond" means that you are unable to talk with them or that by respond you mean come out to your house as in respond like a police call or sim. If you can talk with them, perhaps they can give some information that would be helpful, surely they must have some ideas in mind about the issue. Also, review this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14203/what-would-cause-air-to-be-pushed-into-pipes-from-a-well-tank